# Need help understing this short C++ program and its vulnerability

Tags: c++, linux, security, buffer-overflow, command-execution

I would love if someone could explain me exactly what the code does. I know there's a buffer overflow and bash command execution vulnerability - but since I'm a network guy and not a programmer, I really could use some help to understand the entire code. Thanks in advance!

```
int main () {
    int status;
    char t[1024]="ps -eo lstart,cmd | grep ";
    cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"<<endl;
    char *value = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
    strcat(t,value);
    status = system(strcat(t," | grep -v grep | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $1\" \"$3\" \"$2\" \"$5\" \"$4}'"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not C code, it is C++.

Comment: You can make it C code by replacing `cout` with the corresponding `printf()` or `puts()` call. (Everything else can be done in C.) Btw. you should add the necessary `#include`s to make this sample complete.

Comment: As for what the code does, well... it does stuff that would be best left to a shell script.

Comment: What the code does is 1) append the contents of the environment variable $QUERY_STRING to the string, `t`, 2) append everything of the second `strcat()` 3) executes the command pipline generated that way. Problems: 1) buffer overflow if the contents of $QUERY_STRING is too big so that everything together exceeds 1023 bytes 2) $QUERY_STRING could content 'evil' commands that would be executed

Comment: Thanks a lot Ingo Leonhardt! :)

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt: since the contents of QUERY_STRING are not quoted in the command, even a little whitespace would be an issue.

Comment: @rici you're absolutely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** This is what your code does, as a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -en "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
ps -eo lstart,cmd | grep init | grep -v $QUERY_STRING | \
head -n 1 | awk '{ print $1" "$3" "$2" "$5" "$4}'
```

---

Now for the longer answer.

#### Rewriting the code

First, let's make that thing into C++ rather than C (like your tag suggests you're asking about) with a bit of error handling, then talk about what's going on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

int main () {
    auto query_string = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
    if (query_string == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't obtain QUERY_STRING environment variable\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (std::string_view{query_string}.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Empty query string (QUERY_STRING environment variable)\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::stringstream command_line;
    command_line 
        << "ps -eo lstart,cmd | grep "
        << query_string 
        << " | grep -v grep | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $1\" \"$3\" \"$2\" \"$5\" \"$4}'";
    std::cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
    return system(command_line.str()); // security vulnerability, see below
}
```

#### What are we doing here?

So, we're creating a command-line here which we then execute using the `system()` function. It's an invocation of a `ps` command with some switches, followed by some text processing with `grep`, `head` and `awk` - using the pipe mechanism to move the output of each command to the next. They key part is that we use the environment variable `QUERY_STRING` to filter the `ps` results, i.e. we list processes which match some phrase. If we compile this program, set the environment variable and run, this is what it looks like:

```
$ export QUERY_STRING=init
$ ./the_program
Content-type:text/html


Sun 3 Jun 2018 21:48:56
```

What this has given us is the start time of the first process whose command-line doesn't include the phrase "init". So now you can guess my system has been up since yesterday...

Finally, as a network guy, you probably realize the "Content-type" mumbo-jumbo and the double-newline is a MIME header, so this output is probably intended to be used as an HTTP response. Probably this is intended as some sort of CGI script.

#### Security vulnerabilities

1. In the original code, the buffer size was arbitrarily limited to 1024 - while there was nothing limiting QUERY_SIZE not to be longer than that. If it is longer, you would have memory corruption, which can have security implications; and an attacker would likely be able to figure out your memory layout, so it's more dangerous. This is gone with the C++ version.
2. The second vulnerability has to do with the `system` command. We're injecting an arbitrary string into the string we're creating; and there's nothing preventing someone from setting

   ```
   $export QUERY_STRING="dummy; rm -rf $HOME ; echo"
   ```

   in which case you would run:

   ```
   ps -eo lstart,cmd | grep dummy; rm -rf $HOME ; echo | grep -v init | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $1" "$3" "$2" "$5" "$4}'
   ```

   and this would delete everything under the effective user's home directory. Or it could be any command, including compilation of a custom C/C++ program to run some arbitrary code on your system. Very bad.
3. Even if you sanitized QUERY_STRING to only be a valid grep pattern, there might still be a denial-of-service attack if someone were to supply complex, ultra-long grep'ing patterns somehow. So limiting the length is also a good idea.

Comment: I wouldn't call that code a "proper C++" -- it is considerably less efficient and harder on eyes than original. Plus, it still contains injection vulnerability.

Comment: @C.M.: Point taken about the vulnerability, but I did mark it as such. As for efficiency - this is not a consideration here. Do you mean the construction of several strings? You're right, I could have used a `std::stringstream`, but I thought this would be simpler. Changed now.

Comment: I was protesting use of "proper" noun here -- since new code is more verbose than old one, it makes an impression that "proper C++" code is more verbose than C. Which [isn't necessarily the case](https://godbolt.org/g/cwVn6F). I would also object the notion that C++ means "use iostreams for i/o" -- there is nothing wrong with using cstdlib/etc in C++ code, in fact in my experience iostreams lib creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: @C.M.: Well, making the old code do what the new code does would make it even more verbose still; but then, I don't mind more verbosity if it's not terrible and redundant, and if it allows for clarify. Also - the old code was using iostreams for I/O already - that's not something I added. I'm not particularly fond of iostreams either.

Answer (score 0):

This just declares the variable `status`

```
int status;
```

This declared t, with the C-String "ps -eo lstart,cmd | grep ".
`t` has a maximum of 1024 bytes in capacity (1023 for string + 1 byte for `\0`)

```
char t[1024]="ps -eo lstart,cmd | grep ";
```

Print the string below

```
cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"<<endl;
```

get environment variable `QUERY_STRING`

```
char *value = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
```

concatenate the value above to `t`. Here you may have the buffer overflow because you don't know the size of the string in `value` and it may be longer than 1024 bytes

```
strcat(t,value);
```

Invoke the `system()` function for another concatenation of the previous `t` with all these grep, etc, etc commands... here you could have another buffer overflow, once `t` may overflow its 1024 bytes here as well.

```
status = system(strcat(t," | grep -v grep | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $1\" \"$3\" \"$2\" \"$5\" \"$4}'"));
```